# Why a simple linq command is not executed at the second case?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following line at my code.

```
var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date));
```

However I think that the command 
query.Min(y => y.Date) 
is executed for every x.

So I want to do the following

```
    System.DateTime varMinDate = query.Min(y => y.Date);
    var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(varMinDate, x.Date))
```

The type of the field Date at my model is `System.DateTime.`

However, If I change it at the second way, It I get an exception

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Edit

The query mentioned above is the following

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentProgressPerDay
                         where b.Student.Equals(InputStudent)
                         orderby b.Date
                         select b);
```

Why is that? And how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linq-To-Entities but i assume that the translated sql will be optimized by the database and `query.Min(y => y.Date)` is executed only once. At least this would happen with a sub-query  like this in sq-server.

Comment: The "query" is just a query :) which brings a model's data from the database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I do not know if it does that, because a five line code which includes this command, is extremely slow....

Comment: If it's a silly question for the guy who downvoted it, he can help as well

Comment: Can you do `dates.ToString()` on your original code and give us the result, if you are using EntitiyFramework that should give you the SQL it will be sending to the server.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I get this System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[SchoolProject.Models.ProgressPerStudentPerDay,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]

Comment: ok, so looks like it's no longer LIQN to Entities. How is `query` declared? Btw you should really check generated SQL first, instead of trying to fix something without knowing what actually the reason is.

Comment: However you are getting `query` it is not using Entity framework so your Select statement is not being executed on the server. Please include more code showing how you get `query`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks a lot Scott for your answer and comments. My question was edited accordingly.

Comment: Is `query` declared in the same method, or e.g. is it being passed to other method as parameter?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, I use the same method, and it is not passed as parameter

Answer (score 1):

No it only does it once, by doing `query.ToString()` we can see the SQL Entity Framework is going to be generating. Your query generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF (day, [GroupBy1].[A1], [Extent1].[Date]) AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        MIN([Extent2].[Date]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent2] ) AS [GroupBy1]
```

You can see it does a single query to get the minimum value then it joins the result of that query to your `DATEDIFF` where it will reuse that single result over and over.

---

The test program

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var query = context.Foo;
            var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date));

            var result = dates.ToString();

            Debugger.Break();
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So that means that the command query.Min(y => y.Date); is executed only once, and therefore not adding any time complexity at my code?

Comment: Yes, it is executed once then that result set is cross applied to each row you do the `datediff`, however based on your comment about how the string is outputted I don't think you are working with a `IQueryable` object in your first example.

Comment: So what does this means? I am really new to this, and I cannot find it's relation with my question. How does this affects my program, or the part of the code I have posted here?